# Replace particular character in a python string with multiple character and produce two different outputs

Tags: python, string

Use case 1 :

```
str = '?0?'   #str is input string , we need to replace every '?' with [0,1].
```

so the resulting output will be :

```
['000','100','001','101']
```

use case 2 :

```
str = '?0' #input
```

Expected output  :

```
['00','10']
```

use case 3 :

```
str='?'
```

Expected output :

```
['0','1']
```

The length of the string and number of '?' in string may vary for different inputs.

Comment: What have tried so far?

Comment: I see plenty of question marks but no question.

Comment: Are you aware of the differences between strings and integers? Your question suggest you are not, so you may want to read up on beginners tutorials on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to produce all possible products of `[0,1]` for a `?` or the digit itself:

```py
str = '?0?'
[''.join(p) for p in itertools.product(*[['0', '1'] if c == '?' else c for c in str])]
```

Output:

```
['000', '001', '100', '101']
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution , it is exactly what i am looking for.
I am new to the python collections framework , will explore more on itertools to handle similar kind of problems.

Answer (score 0):

Without itertools:

```
s = '?0?'

a = ['']
for c in s:
    a = [b+d for b in a for d in c.replace('?', '01')]

print(a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HckxCoAwDEDRPafIFkWRiosI0oOIQ1sVBWlD2sXTV@ufHnx@0hn8MLLkHHFG0koTgPm4EK1wBEGHl8c4AX79wzYblmHLMD@3QtfJzrdxe0WaWiTVU70CsFw@VabO@QU)